# Print contents of first file of the day

Tags: shell, file, printing

Cronjob runs every hour and generates a file with format yyyy-mm-dd:hhM.txt

Ex: 2020-12-21:0000.txt (Time is not guaranteed to be 0000, can be 0001/2)

I want to print the contents of the first file of the day for the last some days.

I tried this, but it s not working in my zsh on Mac.

```
for ((i=10;i<=21;i++)); do cat `ls -t1 2020-12-$i\* | tail -1`; done
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
for ((i=10;i<=21;i++)); do cat `ls -t1 2020-12-${i}*.txt | tail -1`; done
```